# preserving saturated ideals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

A reliable source made the following claim:

> Suppose CH there is an $\omega_2$-saturated ideal on $\omega_1$.  Then this is preserved by $\mathrm{Add}(\omega_1,\omega_2)$.

**Question 1:**  How do you show this?

**Question 2:**  Is there an example where adding a Cohen subset of $\omega_1$ changes the truth-value of, "There is a saturated ideal on $\omega_1$"?  Perhaps under MM?

Comment: Monroe, this query is out of my ignorance but can you show that adding one Cohen subset of $\omega_1$ preserves this? since this forces diamond, it must possibly kill old (say e.g., the non stationary ideal) saturated ideals.

Comment: I was considering the possibility that the ideal generated by the old saturated ideal stays saturated. Is this ever possible after adding a Cohen subset of $\omega_1$? I will stop blabbering now.

Comment: If $Col(\omega,\omega_1)$ completely embeds into $\mathcal P(\omega_1)/I$, then we can use a variant of Foreman's Duality Theorem to compute the generated ideal and show that it is not saturated.  However in this situation there is another saturated ideal in the extension.  Actually I don't know of a model of CH + saturated ideal + the quotient algebra doesn't have this factor.

Comment: Can you tell me the simplest way to get a model of diamond plus there is a  saturated ideal on $\omega_1$?

Comment: If you Levy collapse a Woodin cardinal to be $\omega_2$ then there is a saturated ideal in the extension. Also diamond holds because it is always forced by this countably closed collapse.

Comment: Can you tell me what the saturated ideal is? A reference will suffice, thanks!

Comment: It is proved here: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2322360.  This is the simplest forcing notion to achieve this, but I find Kunen's (very different) argument from a huge cardinal easier, which is described in Foreman's Handbook chapter.  Diamond also holds in Kunen's model because a countably closed collapse is used in the second and final stage.